# Python - I can't see my what my error is because the window disappears immediately

Tags: python, syntax-error, runtime-error, message

I am pretty new to Python and I have been pretty annoyed with this problem. I am not sure if this matters, but I run my .py file with Python 2.7.6 with python installed on my computer, not using it on any online thing or other program. Every time I come across an error, my program works fine until it comes to the error, but the window disappears right before I can possibly read whatever the error said it was... Anyways, I haven't been able to find out what is wrong with my programming, and I am tired of guessing and guessing what is wrong. How can I extend the time so I can read the error message? Or something like that? Thanks

Comment: Open a new console and run your script from the command line would leave the window open.

Comment: There are several solutions that require running from a cmd box, but it would be nice to be able to have the window stay open on error so that when a user (a person who runs programs with mouse clicks, not from the command line) has an error, they can report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as @shortfellow said, running it from the terminal should work:

python your_file.py

Another tip that helps in Python, if you are having a hard time with errors, is to use iPython for debugging/testing code on the spot. You can give it a try.

http://ipython.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should run it from command window/terminal instead of double clicking on the file.